# Android - ListView getting populated twice

Tags: android, listview

I am using the following piece of code to populate my ListView -

```
setListAdapter(new NotifListAdapter(this));
```

I call this in the onCreate() method of my activity, and the first time it is created, it populates fine. But when I go back and return to this activity it shows twice as many rows in the List! I have checked my db and its definitely not a backend issue. Also, when I force close the activity and restart it again, it populates fine. Could anybody provide an insight into the issue?

where this is the list adapter -

```
public class NotifListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public NotifListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rnList.size();
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        NotifView nv;

        RichNotification rn = rnList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            nv = new NotifView(mContext, rn.getSubject(),
                    rn.getContent(), rn.getDate());
        } else {
            nv = (NotifView) convertView;
            nv.setTitle(rn.getSubject());
            nv.setDialogue(rn.getContent());
            nv.setDate(rn.getDate());
        }

        return nv;
    }

    /**
     * Remember our context so we can use it when constructing views.
     */
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is rnList being set? Could this be being populated twice?

Comment: The only suggestion would be to put Toast messages into life-cycle methods and into getView() and getCount() and to look the order how it is called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your adapter is displaying data from `rnList`: you are probably adding new objects to `rnList` without clearing it first, which is why you are getting twice as many rows when you return to the Activity. Before you add data to `rnList` call `rnList.clear();` and that should probably fix your problem.

Comment: I had been screwing around for over 2 hours before i found this, thanks!